# Groovy Jersey Client Can't Unmarshall XML

Tags: java, xml, rest, groovy

I have a Java Jersey client that works fine unmarshalling XML to a POJO from passed data from a Jersey web service, but the same equivalent Groovy script gets Parsing and NullPointer exceptions.  Has anyone run into this?  Is there something extra I need to do to get this to work with Groovy?

We use Groovy for Spock testing.  I have also run into the same issue marshalling XML data when I call a POST service with Groovy.

Here's the server code:

```
@GET
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML)
public JAXBElement<WidgetType> getWidget() {
    return new JAXBElement<WidgetType>(new QName("widget"), WidgetType.class, widget);
}
```

Here's the Java client which works fine:

```
    // Create widget from XSD generated class "WidgetType"
    WidgetType widget = new WidgetType();

    // Get - Fetch data from server "query"
    // Unmarshall Generic XML data to type
    GenericType<JAXBElement<WidgetType>> genericXMLWidgetType = new GenericType<JAXBElement<WidgetType>>() {};
    widget = (WidgetType) widgetService.request(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML_TYPE).get(genericXMLWidgetType).getValue();
```

Here's the Groovy code that gets a ProcessingException and NullPointerException apparently while unmarshalling the XML data:

```
// Create widget from XSD generated class "WidgetType"
WidgetType widget = new WidgetType()

// Get - Fetch data from server "query"
// Unmarshall Generic XML data to type
GenericType<JAXBElement<WidgetType>> genericXMLWidgetType = new GenericType<JAXBElement<WidgetType>>() {}
widget = (WidgetType) widgetService.request(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML_TYPE).get(genericXMLWidgetType).getValue()
```

Here's the RAW XML Data sent back:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="true"?>
<widget>
<WidgetId>1</WidgetId>
</widget>
```

Comment: Any more details about the exceptions? Messages?

Comment: The the first exception:  Caught: 
javax.ws.rs.ProcessingException: Unexpected error during response processing.
...
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException

Comment: I determined that if the Groovy script calls a Java method to perform this Jersey call, it still fails! Is there something going on e.g. contexts, threads, etc. that is causing this Groovy->Java failure?  Here are my versions:  Groovy Version: 2.2.0 JVM: 1.7.0_17 Vendor: Oracle Corporation OS: Windows 7

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved it. Jersey has its own JAXB API Jar file. I took that out of the Groovy CLASSPATH and now everything works. There was a similar posting about GRAILS failing with the same error:

http://grails.1312388.n4.nabble.com/Classloading-goes-bad-tp4431718p4435106.html